# Ansible loop list of items and pass item as variable to 'include' tasks with 'when' condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I have attempted various forms of the following task:

```yaml
- include: patch.yml application="{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ all_web_apps }}"
  when: >
    (ansible_hostname in groups['internal'] and 
     item in web_apps)
```

The task without the `loop` statement works fine; when the application is defined manually.
When running the task using the `loop` statement the following output is returned for each iteration but nothing gets ran:

```yaml
included: /tmp/awx_1675_1sa7cu1q/project/roles/webapps/tasks/patch.yml for <some-host>
```

The same output gets displayed even when the output is set to `verbose`.

When running the same task without the `when` condition (see code below) I get the exact same result.

```yaml
- include: patch-copy.yml 
  vars:
    application: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ all_web_apps }}"
```

So it seems like it includes the play but it doesn't run it.

Worth mentioning that this is being ran in AWX and not directly via command line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds as if the `when` condition is always evaluation to `false`. If you create a debug task with the same `when` condition, does it ever run?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the exact same tasks but without the `loop` and it worked.  The `when` condition used a variable instead of `item`.

Comment: Part of  your `when` condition involves the loop item, so you can't test this without a loop. If you could update your question to show (a) the debug task I suggested and (b) the result of running that task, that would help us figure out what's going on.

Comment: There is a case where the `when` condition is evaluated to `false` and I get the `skipping: ` output.

Comment: ok @larsks - will do